# Bind similar looking column names (data.frame or list class)

Tags: r

I'm new to R. Now I have some strange data which is given to me, as shown below by `str(x)`, as you can see each new entry is delimited by a new column (e.g. `$ sold.listPrice`  and `$ sold.listPrice.1` ), whom really should be in the same column.

How can I easily loop over all columns and "aggregate" the values into a single column for each unique column name up to the "delimiter"? Issue at hand is that there may be up to 3000 unique values, and thus also 3000 unique rows that need to be aggregated.

Code output

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  118 variables:
 $ totalCount                             : int 37544
 $ count                                  : int 5
 $ sold.location.streetAddress            : Factor w/ 1 level "Fleminggatan 107": 1
 $ sold.location.position.latitude        : num 59.3
 $ sold.location.position.longitude       : num 18
 $ sold.location..Kungsholmen.            : Factor w/ 1 level "Kungsholmen": 1
 $ sold.location.region.municipalityName  : Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholm": 1
 $ sold.location.region.countyName        : Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholms län": 1
 $ sold.location.ocean                    : int 2507
 $ sold.listPrice                         : int 3295000
 $ sold.rent                              : int 1961
 $ sold.floor                             : int 2
 $ sold.livingArea                        : int 39
 $ sold.source.name                       : Factor w/ 1 level "Edward & Partners Fastighetsmäklare AB": 1
 $ sold.source.id                         : int 410
 $ sold.source.type                       : Factor w/ 1 level "Broker": 1
 $ sold.source.url                        : Factor w/ 1 level "http://www.edwardpartners.se/": 1
 $ sold.rooms                             : int 2
 $ sold.published                         : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-07-10 16:45:52": 1
 $ sold.constructionYear                  : int 1909
 $ sold.objectType                        : Factor w/ 1 level "Lägenhet": 1
 $ sold.booliId                           : int 1918163
 $ sold.soldDate                          : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-07-21": 1
 $ sold.soldPrice                         : int 3920000
 $ sold.url                               : Factor w/ 1 level "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/kungsholmen/fleminggatan+107/1918163": 1
 $ sold.location.streetAddress.1          : Factor w/ 1 level "Astrakangatan 110A": 1
 $ sold.location.position.latitude.1      : num 59.4
 $ sold.location.position.longitude.1     : num 17.8
 $ sold.location..Hässelby.               : Factor w/ 1 level "Hässelby": 1
 $ sold.location.region.municipalityName.1: Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholm": 1
 $ sold.location.region.countyName.1      : Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholms län": 1
 $ sold.listPrice.1                       : int 1900000
 $ sold.rent.1                            : int 4678
 $ sold.floor.1                           : int 1
 $ sold.livingArea.1                      : int 60
 $ sold.source.name.1                     : Factor w/ 1 level "HusmanHagberg": 1
 $ sold.source.id.1                       : int 1610
 $ sold.source.type.1                     : Factor w/ 1 level "Broker": 1
 $ sold.source.url.1                      : Factor w/ 1 level "http://www.husmanhagberg.se/": 1
 $ sold.rooms.1                           : int 2
 $ sold.published.1                       : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-07-17 22:10:35": 1
 $ sold.constructionYear.1                : int 2006
 $ sold.objectType.1                      : Factor w/ 1 level "Lägenhet": 1
 $ sold.booliId.1                         : int 1920703
 $ sold.soldDate.1                        : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-07-21": 1
 $ sold.soldPrice.1                       : int 2000000
 $ sold.url.1                             : Factor w/ 1 level "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/hasselby/astrakangatan+110a/1920703": 1
 $ sold.location.streetAddress.2          : Factor w/ 1 level "Borensvägen 12": 1
 $ sold.location.position.latitude.2      : num 59.3
 $ sold.location.position.longitude.2     : num 18.1
 $ sold.location..Årsta.                  : Factor w/ 1 level "Årsta": 1
 $ sold.location.region.municipalityName.2: Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholm": 1
 $ sold.location.region.countyName.2      : Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholms län": 1
 $ sold.location.ocean.1                  : int 3017
 $ sold.listPrice.2                       : int 2295000
 $ sold.rent.2                            : int 2988
 $ sold.floor.2                           : int 1
 $ sold.livingArea.2                      : int 52
 $ sold.source.name.2                     : Factor w/ 1 level "Fastighetsbyrån": 1
 $ sold.source.id.2                       : int 1573
 $ sold.source.type.2                     : Factor w/ 1 level "Broker": 1
 $ sold.source.url.2                      : Factor w/ 1 level "http://www.fastighetsbyran.se/": 1
 $ sold.rooms.2                           : int 2
 $ sold.published.2                       : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-07-04 01:08:46": 1
 $ sold.constructionYear.2                : int 1945
 $ sold.objectType.2                      : Factor w/ 1 level "Lägenhet": 1
 $ sold.booliId.2                         : int 1915578
 $ sold.soldDate.2                        : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-07-21": 1
 $ sold.soldPrice.2                       : int 2550000
 $ sold.url.2                             : Factor w/ 1 level "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/arsta/borensvagen+12/1915578": 1
 $ sold.location.streetAddress.3          : Factor w/ 1 level "Helsingörsgatan 5": 1
 $ sold.location.position.latitude.3      : num 59.4
 $ sold.location.position.longitude.3     : num 17.9
 $ sold.location..Kista.                  : Factor w/ 1 level "Kista": 1
 $ sold.location.region.municipalityName.3: Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholm": 1
 $ sold.location.region.countyName.3      : Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholms län": 1
 $ sold.listPrice.3                       : int 3295000
 $ sold.rent.3                            : int 5226
 $ sold.floor.3                           : int 5
 $ sold.livingArea.3                      : int 100
 $ sold.source.name.3                     : Factor w/ 1 level "HusmanHagberg": 1
 $ sold.source.id.3                       : int 1610
 $ sold.source.type.3                     : Factor w/ 1 level "Broker": 1
 $ sold.source.url.3                      : Factor w/ 1 level "http://www.husmanhagberg.se/": 1
 $ sold.rooms.3                           : int 5
 $ sold.published.3                       : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-06-23 21:56:06": 1
 $ sold.constructionYear.3                : int 1978
 $ sold.objectType.3                      : Factor w/ 1 level "Lägenhet": 1
 $ sold.booliId.3                         : int 1911573
 $ sold.soldDate.3                        : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-07-21": 1
 $ sold.soldPrice.3                       : int 3330000
 $ sold.url.3                             : Factor w/ 1 level "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/kista/helsingorsgatan+5/1911573": 1
 $ sold.location.streetAddress.4          : Factor w/ 1 level "Ekholmsvägen 220": 1
 $ sold.location.position.latitude.4      : num 59.3
 $ sold.location.position.longitude.4     : num 17.9
 $ sold.location..Skärholmen.             : Factor w/ 1 level "Skärholmen": 1
 $ sold.location.region.municipalityName.4: Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholm": 1
 $ sold.location.region.countyName.4      : Factor w/ 1 level "Stockholms län": 1
 $ sold.listPrice.4                       : int 2600000
  [list output truncated]
```

Comment: You can construct a vector of strings that are used to look up column names. You use partial matching or full blown regex to scan through all the columns and then somehow (you don't say how, i.e. if values are conflicting since both are not NA) combine values.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a dirty solution, but it should work if there are always the same number of additional columns. If this is changing, this code might fail.

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=rnorm(5),c=rnorm(5),b.1=rnorm(5),c.1=rnorm(5),b.2=rnorm(5),c.2=rnorm(5))
df

addition_columns <- grep('.*\\.[0-9]+$', names(df), value=T)
original_columns <- unique(sub('(.*)\\.[0-9]+$', '\\1', addition_columns))
fitting_original_columns <- sub('(.*)\\.[0-9]+$', '\\1', addition_columns)
single_columns <- names(df)[!names(df) %in% c(addition_columns, original_columns)]

df2 <- data.frame(df[c(single_columns, original_columns)])
while(length(addition_columns) > 0) {
  jnk_df <- data.frame(df[single_columns],
                       df[addition_columns[match(original_columns, fitting_original_columns)]])
  names(jnk_df) <- c(single_columns, original_columns)
  addition_columns <- addition_columns[-match(original_columns, fitting_original_columns)]
  df2 <- rbind(df2, 
               jnk_df)
}
df2
```